# How can I render these Bootstrap 3 panels inline?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

[Here's the Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/Ea2VDr0frh)

How can i render these panels tp be inline? I don't see what I'm missing here, i have a `container`, I have a `row`, I have the `col-md-4` nested within the row?

For context, each of those panels is written in a '_quotes.html.erb' partial, which is rendered by a `Quotes.all.each` block within the  'index.html.erb' view.

index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <% @quotes.each do |quote| %>
          <%= render :partial => "quote", locals: {quote: quote} %>
        <% end %>
</div>
```

_quote.html.erb

```
    <% @quote = local_assigns[:quote] %>
<%= link_to quote_path(@quote) do %>
    <section id="quotes">
        <!-- <div class="container"> -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-4 col-md-4 text-center">
            <div class="panel panel-success panel-quote link-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <strong>GLA</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
               <p><strong>Quote ID; <%= @quote.id %></strong></p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tr>
                <td>Company name</td>
                <td><%= @quote.co_name %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Company number</td>
                <td><%= @quote.co_number %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Office postcode</td>
                <td><%= @quote.postcode %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Industry</td>
                <td><%= @quote.industry %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Previous cover</td>
                <td><%= @quote.prev_cover %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Lives overseas</td>
                <td><%= @quote.lives_overseas %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Scheme start date</td>
                <td><%= @quote.scheme_start_date %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Payment frequency</td>
                <td><%= @quote.payment_frequency %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Commission level</td>
                <td><%= @quote.commission_level %></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      <!-- </div> -->
    </section>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of mistakes

1. You have only a single col-md-4 which means all children will fit to that single column.
2. You have another container div inside your col-md-4 which basicly resets the whole thing and again a single col-md-4 in there.

[Edited Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/TJtmozRRAC)

Comment: ok, nice thanks #shadowfox, I can now get it working fine in the Bootply, updated as above, but in my actual RoR application the first two records do not render inline, but underneath each other, only the 3rd 4th and 5th records then appear inline. Code updated in question body above, any ideas whats going on here?

Comment: I think the updating of the bootply failed, as it shows me the one I made for you :)